# Postgresql select user if row of roles is one

Tags: postgresql

I did it:

```
SELECT u.username, u.abilitazione, u.email, u.nome, u.cognome, r.ruolo 
FROM public.utenti AS u 
JOIN public.ruoli_utente AS r 
on u.username=r.username 
WHERE r.ruolo='ROLE_ADMIN'
UNION
SELECT u.username, u.abilitazione, u.email, u.nome, u.cognome, r.ruolo 
FROM public.utenti AS u 
JOIN public.ruoli_utente AS r 
on u.username=r.username 
WHERE u.username 
NOT IN (
SELECT username FROM public.ruoli_utente
WHERE ruolo='ROLE_ADMIN'
)
ORDER BY username;
```

---

I have two tables:

```
--- table utenti
CREATE TABLE public.utenti
(
  username character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  abilitazione boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  email character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(45),
  cognome character varying(45),
  CONSTRAINT username PRIMARY KEY (username)
)

--- table ruoli_utente
CREATE TABLE public.ruoli_utente
(
  user_role_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ruoli_utente_user_role_id_seq'::regclass),
  username character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  ruolo character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_role_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id),
  CONSTRAINT username_fk FOREIGN KEY (username)
      REFERENCES public.utenti (username) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

from this query I obtain all the information I need in my project:

```
SELECT u.username, u.abilitazione, u.email, u.nome, u.cognome, r.ruolo 
FROM public.utenti AS u 
JOIN public.ruoli_utente AS r 
on u.username=r.username 
ORDER BY username
```

the result I obtain is this:
[image: result of the query]

But instead I would like to obtain one row where the user have a role with ROLE_ADMIN (in the example the result without the row 3 and 4). How could I do?

Comment: So, you want to get only one of rows per user which has ROLE ADMIN or only *one* of those rows overall which has ROLE ADMIN ?

Comment: Use  `ROW_NUMBER() ORDER BY ruolo='ROLE ADMIN',ruolo` then filter by rn=1

Comment: only one of rows per user which has ROLE ADMIN

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved with this:

```
SELECT u.username, u.abilitazione, u.email, u.nome, u.cognome, r.ruolo 
FROM public.utenti AS u 
JOIN public.ruoli_utente AS r 
on u.username=r.username 
WHERE r.ruolo='ROLE_ADMIN'
UNION
SELECT u.username, u.abilitazione, u.email, u.nome, u.cognome, r.ruolo 
FROM public.utenti AS u 
JOIN public.ruoli_utente AS r 
on u.username=r.username 
WHERE u.username 
NOT IN (
SELECT username FROM public.ruoli_utente
WHERE ruolo='ROLE_ADMIN'
)
ORDER BY username;
```

Comment: don't know who give me thumbs down and why, but I answered my question to share the result to who could need it. If you want best answer just answer with your solution (could be many) and I will test it.